# Why is there no name for the precision of the negative class in the assessment of a binary classifer?

Tags: metrics, precision-recall

In the assessment of a binary classifier, we know that specificity is the recall of the negative class.
So there are clear names for both flavors of recall.

Then looking at precision, I can't help but wonder why there isn't an analogous version for the negative class, ala

tn / (tn + fn)

It seems useful to ask, "of all the sample predicted as negative, how many are really negative?" so you'd think that metric would have it's own name. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/424737/is-there-a-name-for-this-metric-tn-tn-fn, but still nobody knows, why isn't this metric as commonly reported as the others?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a name for it: [negative predictive value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_predictive_values#Negative_predictive_value_(NPV)).

Comment: wow. I'm starting to wonder why the classification report for sklearn doesn't have this, or a micro-average either